# Editing a string in the result of a reactapp built with "yarn build" without rebuilding

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, yarnpkg

I have some reactapp that I build using `yarn build --production`.
In that app there is some string that I want to modify after the process is over. e.g:

```
const version_string="SOME_PLACE_HOLDER_STRING";

export version_string
```

After finishing the build I store the created "build" directory, and once it's there I want to be able to replace this string and get a working `build` directory as if `version_string` was replaced in code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing you typically handle within your webpack configuration, using something like the `string-replace-loader`. Since create-react-app handles all of your webpack stuff, you're likely getting to a point that you'll have to `eject` from create-react-app to handle more customized build configurartions.

```js
// As a module.rules config item, somewhere
// after your babel-loader config
{
  test: /somefileglob\.js$/, // only test the files you'll change
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'string-replace-loader',
      options: {
        search: 'my_string_to_replace',
        replace: my_replacement_variable
      }
    }
  [
}
```

Comment: This will working during the build and OP wants to do it when the build is completed.

Answer (score 0):

start with index.html from build folder and find string which you want to update,

only if you can find your string else you have to rebuild :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to edit the value of `version_string` after the production build is done.

In that case you have no choice but to open the generated (transpiled) file that holds value of that variable and edit it. By default `create-react-app` will generate multiple files, so you'll need to find the file where `version_string` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar at my work with an npm script that does something like

```
"build": webpack --mode-production && node replaceProductionStrings.js
```

And you can write a node script (or use anything else you want) that will parse your entire production codebase and replace the strings as you need.